# Noun form of "free of something"?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I'm trying to rewrite the following sentence into another form:

> Client requires that the software run with high performance and **be bug-free**.

My rewrite looks like this:

> Client has strong demand for high performance and ______ from the software.

I'm looking for the noun form of "be free from bugs" for the blank. I hope that the solution is general, because in the future I will try to rewrite "loyalty-free", "alcohol-free" etc. in a similar fashion.

Comment: You are just making things more complicated. **Client requires high-performance, bug-free software** (or....bug-free, high-performance software**

Comment: @RonaldSole It's a simplified example that serves just the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: **bug-free** is an adjective. It doesn't come as a noun.  Ditto your other "frees"

Comment: Your only options are words such as **reliability, stability, dependability""

Comment: This is specific to software and maybe a little jargon-y, but I would say “robustness.”

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a direct noun equivalent of "bug-free" because by its nature that is an adjective.

It would be possible to contrive a ridiculous word like **buglessness** (from the invented adjective **bug-less**), but I would never expect to hear that in any serious situation.

Sometimes you just need to modify your sentence. You could choose to simply add an appropriate noun to go with your adjective, and this might work well in your sentence because your "performance" part does exactly that:

> Client has strong demand for high performance and **bug-free operation** from the software.

That being said, there is nothing wrong with your original sentence from which you were attempting to move away.

Edit: To answer your actual point about being free of other things, some will use '-lessness' (e.g. **carelessness**), and some use various other forms (e.g. adding 'un-' as in **unreliability**, free from reliability).

Answer (score -1):

Defect-free is better, there could be defects in the software that are not bugs, such as a defect in the media, incorrect or out of date instruction manuals, interconnection issues, etc.

"Compliant" might also be used.

Comment: Are you sure "defect-free" serves as a noun?

Comment: It's not, as you pointed out above. But it fills in the blank. Try "compliance."